# The Nephilim and Abortions?

Tags: genesis, hebrew-bible, flood

Since the semantic range for the Hebrew root *nphl* can indicate a miscarriage* (1), or even an abortion (2) (as it does in modern Hebrew today), is it possible that the Genesis 6:4 reading regarding the Nephilim (which shares the same root *nphl*) (3)(4)(5), instead of referring to some form of "giants", relates instead to an antediluvian form of abortion?

As such, it would begin something like this:

"[Abortions] were [in] the earth in those days..."

From the passage, I've come away with a few contextual clues that might help establish the possibility that "abortions" might be considered here as accurate. They are as follows:

1.) The context of the passage is primarily about sexual relationships/marriages and the conception of children (See Genesis 6:1-4, “men began to multiple”, “daughters born”, “took them wives”, God talking about His Spirit and human flesh, which, when joined into one, creates human life or living souls [see Genesis 2:7], “came in unto the daughter of men”, and “bare them children”).

2.) Genesis 6:5-7 speaks of the LORD seeing the great wickedness of humanity upon the earth, i.e. that every imagination of the human heart was continuously evil. For that reason, God sorrowed within Himself for having created the human race, and decided to annihilate it. Is it possible the murder of an unborn child is considered by God to be the height of  this wickedness?

3.) Noah, his children, and their wives, were the only ones who survived the Flood. This would mean that Goliath, the Anakims, Emims, and Rephaims, as giants (Cf. Numbers 13:33), do not appear to be descended from some other especially strange race of human-demon hybrids. If so, these giants then, though gigantic, are still humans only, somehow descended from Noah and his offspring.

4.) Fallen angels are spirits, and cannot marry, the institution through which God ordained human procreation (Cf. Matthew 22:30, Mark 122:25, and Luke 20:35-36, with Genesis 1:28). To do so would seemingly require an act of God as their Creator, to allow them or give them the ability to do so, something apparently He did not do by not allowing them to be "given in marriage" prior to their fall (since, according to Jesus, holy angels are not given in marriage [in order to procreate, ostensibly]; therefore it follows that fallen angels, prior to their fall, were likewise restricted from being given in marriage for the purposes of procreation, therefore, ontologically speaking, the ability to procreate would not be added to their nature as spirits, post-fall, except through special divine endowment).

Notwithstanding the above, is it possible to conclusively prove either for or against the idea that the Nephilim refer to aborted human fetuses?

*Miscarriages are also called "spontaneous abortions. See here: https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/001488.htm.

Footnotes:

(1) http://biblehub.com/hebrew/5309.htm

(2) https://www.pealim.com/dict/3823-hapala/

(3) http://biblehub.com/interlinear/genesis/6-4.htm

(4) http://biblehub.com/hebrew/5303.htm

(5) http://biblehub.com/hebrew/5307.htm

Comment: It is problematic to back-read into the text a the semantic range of a word in modern Hebrew to an indirectly related word in OT Hebrew. In general it is problematic to try to back-read modern (i.e. first century BCE and onwards) concepts into the OT texts. Since this question is in fact a speculation based on such a back-reading, it is likely to be closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because abortions cannot result in children - especially ones who grew into heroes of old, men of renown. The premise doesn't even make a little bit of sense.

Comment: @JamesShewey - that seems like a potential answer to the question.  Since the question is addressing the interpretation of a specific Biblical text, how is it off-topic?

Comment: @user33515 - I have recently resolved to better explain (my) close votes. The reason the premise doesn't make sense is for the close reasons everyone else selected. *Because* this passage isn't about abortion, it is not about the analysis of biblical text within the scope defined because it is not seeking an answer about ① the history of this biblical text or ② the meaning of this biblical text either in context or through a process of arriving at a particular interpretation. Half of the passage is being taken out of context to get a modern interpretation.

Comment: @JamesShewey yes, but he did have a process.  I don't think anyone agreed with it, but it was a process.   I don't think the people closing the question are being objective

Comment: @user33515 - When and why a question should be closed might be a great discussion for [the library](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) or [meta](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/). I'm going to stand by this one for numerous reasons to lengthy to enumerate here (due to the length of my philosophical position, not necessarily the number of reasons). If you feel strongly about this question feel free to make your case and nominate it for re-opening.

Answer (score 3):

The word for a miscarried child is *nephel* (נֵפֶל, cf. Job 3:16), not *naphil* (נָפִיל). The word "abortion" (הַפָּלָה in later Hebrew) doesn't appear in the Bible (discounting this case). Exodus 21:22 gives the case of two people fighting and accidentally causing a woman to miscarry. The paradigm case of abortion is apparently accidental miscarriage, not the intentional miscarriage that the word "abortion" usually means today.

The Nephilim are also mentioned in Numbers 13:33, and context rules out the translation "abortions." They are called "the sons of giants" there. Whether the Nephilim in Numbers are descended from Noah or not is irrelevant: The same word "Nephilim" can't mean "abortions" in the context there. The verse here in Genesis which calls them "heroes" (הַגִּבֹּרִים) is also understood better if Nephilim are giants, not "abortions."

Answer (score 1):

Answers and comments to your question have already addressed the fact that Numbers 13:33 seems to preclude interpreting the word as you suggest.

Furthermore, if you accept the Septuagint as a valid witness to the proto-Hebrew text, there is further evidence that the word really was understood to mean giants (it appears as γίγαντες - *gigantes*). The Targum and the Talmud also understood the word here to mean *giant* (see e.g. [Rashi's commentary](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8171/jewish/Chapter-6.htm#showrashi=true)).

It seems that we have  2-3 millennia of educated Jews who understood Genesis 6:4 to refer to giants.

Answer (score -2):

Nephilim has the meaning 'something fallen'.

Strong 5309 [(**Biblehub**)](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/5309.htm) :

> Or nephel {nay'-fel}; from naphal; something fallen, i.e. An abortion -- untimely birth.

The root idea of 'something fallen' is used, in context, where an aborted foetus is expelled.

That root idea is taken and applied to the appalling conditions in the old world after the 'sons of God' left their first estate, Jude 6, and conjoined with humanity. The result of that unwarranted conjunction was nephilim.

It was an aborted process. It did not result in a living human.

It resulted in something else.